# Why does my MBP perform poorly compared to an identical model with less RAM?

Tags: memory, performance, macbook-pro

I recently discovered [Geekbench](http://www.primatelabs.com/geekbench/) and ran a set of tests to benchmark my laptop (Early 2011 Macbook Pro / 16 GB RAM of 1333  DD3 RAM / 2.3 GHZ quad core).

Here are [the results of the tests](http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench3/385690) (Early 2011 Macbook Pro / 16 GB RAM / 2.3 GHZ quad core). Here are [the results of the tests](http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench3/385396) for an identical Macbook Pro with 8 GB of 1333 MHZ DD3 RAM (which I refer to as the baseline model).

The performance is actually pretty similar for most of the tests, EXCEPT when it comes to RAM benchmarks (see the details Memory Performance). When it comes to RAM benchmarks, my laptop can only achieves about half as well as the baseline model even though it has twice the RAM.

I'm wondering if this suggests that there's something wrong with my RAM (I replaced it myself a year ago so it isn't Apple OEM, though it has the same specs).

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The link you provide isn't for an identical model. The CPU is two generations later and the RAM is faster.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! It looks like I posted the wrong link, so I went ahead and fixed it. That said the issue still stands.

Comment: The only possible explanation is you have some process running sqewing the results

Comment: Have you performed an SMC reset (and possibly also an NVRAM reset)? Did you install 2x8GB or 1x16GB?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Yes! I did perform an SMC reset + NVRAM reset. The MBP has 2 x 8 GB.